# docker-desktop does not launch on ubuntu [Failed to start docker-desktop.service: Unit docker-desktop.service is masked]

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop

I experienced this issue on `Ubuntu 22.04 jammy`.

After installing `Docker Desktop` following the instructions on the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/), and meeting system requirements including having virtualization support, I am unable to launch `Docker Desktop`. I tried launching it from the applications menu but nothing. As an alternative to launching `Docker Desktop` from the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/#launch-docker-desktop), I opened the terminal to run:

`systemctl --user start docker-desktop`

but I got this error:

`Failed to start docker-desktop.service: Unit docker-desktop.service is masked`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update March 2024:**

The previously opened issue has been closed. This is because the workaround (from the original answer) has been accepted as the solution

**Original answer:**

It turns out this is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/94) on the docker desktop-linux (Docker Desktop for Linux) repository on GitHub.

The solution is to unmask the service and enable it.

**`Solution:`**

`$ file /etc/xdg/systemd/user/docker-desktop.service`

Running the command above, you should notice that the file is a symlink to `/dev/null`

Delete the file: `$ sudo rm /etc/xdg/systemd/user/docker-desktop.service`

And then enable the service for the user: `$ systemctl --user enable docker-desktop`

credit to @ptarud [comment](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/94#issuecomment-1374356329) on the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Another **GitHub solution** that worked for me after trying many solutions.

Follow these steps:

1. Try to run Docker Desktop using the command line.

   systemctl --user start docker-desktop
2. If not started, then use this command instead.

   systemctl --user force-reload docker-desktop

I hope it works for you guys as well!

Credits: [TahirIqbalGit](https://github.com/TahirIqbalGit)